# A noetherian local ring having a height one principal prime is a domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> $A$ is a commutative ring with with $1$. If $A$ is a *Noetherian* and *local* ring and $A$ has a *principal* prime ideal of *height* $1$ then show that $A$ is a domain.

Can anybody give some hint.I tried to show $(0)$ is a prime ideal in $A$ but I couldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak p=(p)$ be a principal prime of height one. Then there is a prime $\mathfrak q\subsetneq\mathfrak p$. If $\mathfrak q=(0)$ you are done. Otherwise, let $a\in\mathfrak q$, $a\ne 0$. Then $a=pa_1$ and since $p\notin\mathfrak q$ it follows that $a_1\in\mathfrak q$, so $a_1=pa_2$, and so on. Thus $a\in\bigcap_{n\ge0}\mathfrak p^n\subseteq\bigcap_{n\ge0}\mathfrak m^n=(0)$, a contradiction. (Here $\mathfrak m$ denotes the maximal ideal.)

Comment: I have to check why the intersection of maximal ideal powers is 0

Comment: This is given by [Krull's Intersection Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring#Some_facts_and_definitions).

Comment: yes I can remember the great theorem of Krull.. for this Noetherianness is used..thanks @user26857